# Which theorem states that, for $ m>n$, $m$ polynomials in $n$ variables must be algebraically related?

Tags: polynomials

I remember there is a theorem that states that if you have more polynomials than the number of variables, there must be an algebraic relation between them, but I forget what the theorem is called.  (I'd also appreciate if I could be directed to a proof of it.)  Thanks.

Comment: That is a consequence of this theorem; for instance, if f(x)=x^2-1 and g(x)=x, then f-g^2+1=0.

Comment: Here is what looks to be a proof of the result you're looking for, and a very clever one at that! http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282105/transcendence-degree-of-kx-1-x-2-ldots-x-n

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.